# Unable to view media files in django

Tags: django, django-media

I have correctly set the settings for media in settings.py as:-

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and also specified the correct url settings

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.views.static',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',
    'serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

Whenever i upload an image through admin..the image gets uploaded in my media folder but i can't see it when i run my development server...it shows a page not found (404) error...

I think the problem is due to some permissions of uploaded files which is why django shows a 404 page when trying to access them..if someone knows about this please help

Please suggest me a solution 
Thank you!

Comment: I copy-pasted your settings to a clean Django 1.7 app and it worked. Can you show something more?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Relevant url:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: 1.7...i think it is due to some permission of uploaded files that's why i am unable to see the media images

Comment: Like Kos said, your setup works on a clean install... And a permission issue would be more likely to raise an 403. Can you show me your project/app structure? Maybe some things are not in the right place

Answer (score 1):

Do this

---

```
  from django.conf.urls.static import static
  from django.conf import settings

  urlpatterns = patterns('',

  # your urls here. 

  ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```